# how Handler Exception CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I need to capture an Exception in CodeIgniter but I tried different solutions and they don't work.
I want to capture the Exception and print my message.

This is the Exception default page:

http://it.tinypic.com/r/sexf68/8

This is my code:

```
$this->load->database();
$c=300;
$query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ut (u, p, n,c)
VALUES ('$u', '$p', '$n','$c')");
if($query->db->_error_message()){

}
if($$query->db->_error_number()){
    echo" BAU";
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You should paste the exception error into your question in case the link disappears. Also, when I followed the link the page took forever to load, pasting your exception error into your question would also avoid that problem.

Comment: Did you set `true` on 'db_debug' parameter in file `application/config/database.php`.